# UITextView content Inset Bottom not working iOS7

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

UITextView content Inset bottom value is not working in iOS 7.

By not working i mean if i keep typing in UITextView and cursor reaches at end then it hides and i cant see text which i am typing.

I tried

```
[myTextView  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];

[myTextView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
```

But it is not making any effect.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? currently in same situation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961870/ios-7-uitextview-clipping-text/20962015#20962015

Comment: Same here using autolayout without storyboard :/

Answer (score -3):

You might need to turn off automatic scroll view adjustments in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
}
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant.