# iOS 7 - UITextView clipping text

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

I'm trying to fit 3 lines of text in a textview of a certain size by using

```
[_messageField setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8, -6, 0,0)];
```

This works in iOS 6, but iOS 7 seems to be clipping content at the bottom of the textview.  Both of the textviews shown below have the same font, text, and edge insets.  Line 3 does not appear in iOS 7.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had success using

```
[_messageField setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

and adjusting as needed.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm beginning to question the usefulness of UIScrollView methods when dealing with a UITextView that's backed by Text Kit.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue I was having.

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```